# Display Json array in HTML ul

Tags: javascript, html

What can be the error here. I need to add this firstName list to a

```js
var text = '[' +
  '{ "firstName" : "John", "lastName": "Doe"},' +
  '{ "firstName" : "Ann", "lastName": "Smith"},' +
  '{ "firstName" : "Peter", "lastName": "Jones"}]';
  
var arr = JSON.parse(text);

var list = function(employee) {
  for (var i in employee.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<li>' + employee[i].firstName + '</li>';
  }
};

list(arr);
```

```html
<ul id="demo"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi! Why do you use JSON string here? Why not to create an array?

Comment: have you checked your console?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays.

This ought to work.

```
function list(employees) {
    var html = '';
    employees.forEach(function (employee) {
      // Beware of XSS/HTML injection vulnerabilities here;
      // the name is not sanitized and could contain HTML.
      // Implementing sanitization is left as an exercise for the reader.
      html += '<li>' + employee.firstName + '</li>';  
    });
    // Only edit innerHTML once.
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += html;
};

list([  // Let's assume JSON.parse() has been called already.
  { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  { firstName: 'Ann', lastName: 'Smith' },
  { firstName: 'Peter', lastName: 'Jones' },
]);
```

Comment: you have an error in your code. There's an indexer that isn't needed

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are using for .. in loop in a wrong way.
Take a look at [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). It's designed to iterate numerable object properties. So you'd better use [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead

But in my example I also used [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to convert array of objects into array of strings, join it into one string and set as innerHTML of your target node.

I also added comment in my snippet regarding using of `+=` your case. You may find, that you want to clear your list before adding new values in it so maybe better just to assing a value to `innerHTML` so maybe using `array.map` to build a content of list maybe a better option.

```js
const text = '[' +
  '{ "firstName" : "John", "lastName": "Doe"},' +
  '{ "firstName" : "Ann", "lastName": "Smith"},' +
  '{ "firstName" : "Peter", "lastName": "Jones"}]';

const arr = JSON.parse(text);


// using aray.map()
const listNode = document.getElementById('demo')
function makeListItem(employee) {
  return '<li>' + employee.firstName + '</li>'
}

function listEmployees(employees) {
  listNode.innerHTML = employees.map(makeListItem).join('')
}
listEmployees(arr)


//using array.forEach()
const listNode2 = document.getElementById('demo2')
function listWithForEach (employees) {
  employees.forEach(function(employee) {
    listNode2.innerHTML += '<li>'+employee.firstName+'</li>'
  })
}

//using += will append content to your list, so if you call your function twice, you'll get a repeating items. 
listWithForEach(arr)
listWithForEach(arr)
```

```html
<ul id="demo"></ul>

<ul id="demo2"></ul>
```